# Set a custom icon to balloon tooltip using win32gui with python?

Tags: python, windows, notifications, win32gui

I've been seeing a lot of post and question about this in other languages, C# mostly, but not in python.

I'm using windows 10, and when creating a balloon tooltip notification, the custom icon I'm using show itself blurry and with a black field arround it, I've tried with different icons, with different image height and width and none helped, nor did help using images .ico or .png, etc.

All I see to use custom icons is about using options I don't see in the [win32gui documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32gui.html) or extending the tooltip icon class, which I don't think you can do through python.

In other question somebody said that you must use a full path instead using os.path to get the full path, but that didn't help.

This is part of my code, the part where I set the icon:

```
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        icon_path_name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(sys.path[0],
                                                      "notif.ico"))
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
            hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst, icon_path_name,
                                       win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        except:
            hicon = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        flags = win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "tooltip1")
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_MODIFY,
                                  (self.hwnd, 0, win32gui.NIF_INFO,
                                   win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon,
                                   "Notification", msg, 200, title))
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a user-supplied icon for the notification popup (the successor to the balloon tooltip in recent versions of Windows), in `NOTIFYICONDATA` put the icon handle in `hIcon` as usual, and put a value of 4 (`NIIF_USER`) in your `dwInfoFlags`:

```
NIIF_USER = 4
# ...

win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_MODIFY,
                                  (self.hwnd, 0, win32gui.NIF_INFO,
                                   win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon,
                                   "Notification", msg, 200, title, NIIF_USER))
```

([docs for `NOTIFYINFODATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352(v=vs.85).aspx))

I'm not sure what the blurriness & background issues are; all I can suggest is to make sure that the bitmaps in your icon file have appropriate alpha masks, and that you'll want a 32x32 one in there for the system tray and a larger one for the balloon tooltip window, and adjust your `icon_flags` as necessary.

Comment: Here's a class I'm working on for notifications with a persistent notification area icon. https://github.com/rakslice/twitch-notifier/blob/master/windows_10_toast_notifications.py . It really should be reworked to pump window messages regularly rather than only when there is a notification on screen, but it's fine for my current hackish needs.

Comment: I'll try changing things with this and come back with results when I get hold of my computer again, thanks!